# Align subplot with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

I am trying to share the x-axis of a `imshow` that have to be square and a classique plot:

1. the imshow has to be square
2. with a colorbar
3. the plot bellow should share the same axis (or at least look like align with the imshow)

I spent two days on it, and now I am crazy. Did someone know how to align them ?

[image: square imshow on the top, with a color bar, and bellow a plot, that should share the same axis]

The code used to produce the image is bellow.

```
def myplot( Nbin=20 ):

X = np.random.rand(1000)
Y = np.random.rand(1000)
h2, yh2, xh2 = np.histogram2d( Y, X, bins=[Nbin,Nbin] )
h1, xh1 = np.histogram( X, bins=Nbin )
######################################
######################################
fig = plt.figure(  )
gs = gridspec.GridSpec( 3, 2 )
######################################
######################################
ax1 = plt.subplot( gs[:-1,:] )
im = plt.imshow( h2, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',
                 extent=[xh2[0],xh2[-1],yh2[0],yh2[-1]] )
cb = plt.colorbar( im, ax=ax1 )
plt.xlim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
plt.ylim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
ax1.tick_params( axis='x', which='both', bottom='on', top='on', labelbottom='off' )
######################################
######################################
ax2 = plt.subplot( gs[-1,:] )
plt.plot( xh1[:-1] + np.diff(xh1)/2., h1 )
plt.xlim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
cm = plt.cm.Blues
cb2 = plt.colorbar( ax=ax2 )
ax2.tick_params( axis='x', which='both', bottom='on', top='on', labelbottom='on' )
######################################
######################################
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05)
cb2.ax.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could imagine that the easiest way to have the second axes directly below the image is to use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable`. This allows to shrink the image at the expense of the newly created subplot and can equally be used to position the colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

Nbin=20

X = np.random.rand(1000)
Y = np.random.rand(1000)
h2, yh2, xh2 = np.histogram2d( Y, X, bins=[Nbin,Nbin] )
h1, xh1 = np.histogram( X, bins=Nbin )

fig = plt.figure(  )


ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax1.imshow( h2, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',
                 extent=[xh2[0],xh2[-1],yh2[0],yh2[-1]] )

plt.xlim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
plt.ylim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
ax1.tick_params( axis='x', which='both', bottom='on', top='on', labelbottom='off' )


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
ax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="50%", pad=0.08)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.08)
cb = plt.colorbar( im, ax=ax1, cax=cax )

#ax2 = plt.subplot( gs[-1,:] )  # , sharex=ax1
ax2.plot( xh1[:-1] + np.diff(xh1)/2., h1 )
ax2.set_xlim( xh1[0], xh1[-1] )
cm = plt.cm.Blues

ax2.tick_params( axis='x', which='both', bottom='on', top='on', labelbottom='on' )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is such a great answer. There are related answers available on the internet, but this one makes so much sense.