# Align matplotlib subplot axes with and without colorbars (for more than 2 axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you align the axes of different subplots when some have a colorbar and the others don't?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.random.random([15,15])
data2 = np.random.random(15)

fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4], [ax5, ax6]] = plt.subplots(3,2)

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.pcolormesh(data1)
    plt.colorbar()

plt.sca(ax3)
plt.plot(data2)
```

[image]

I would like to add white space to the left of `ax3` so it is aligned with the other figures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning x-axis with sharex using subplots and colorbar with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473465/aligning-x-axis-with-sharex-using-subplots-and-colorbar-with-matplotlib)

Comment: A better one by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682146/align-subplot-with-colorbar) question

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those answers (not sure why they didn't show up in my search). It wasn't clear, however, how those answers translate to my specific case. I updated my question and ask how to do this when there are more than two axes on the figure.

Answer (score 5):

This is on of the things `constrained_layout` is designed to do: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

```py
fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4], [ax5, ax6]] = plt.subplots(3,2,
        constrained_layout=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Note this will fail with tight_layout (which is not needed)

Answer (score 3):

This was the best way so far of how to do this (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473867/2383070).

I still wonder if there is an easier way, like simply adding whitespace to the left side of an axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.random([15,15])
data2 = np.random.random(15)


fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4], [ax5, ax6]] = plt.subplots(3,2)

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    im1 = ax.pcolormesh(data1, cmap='magma')
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=.05)
    plt.colorbar(im1, cax=cax)

im2 = ax3.plot(data2)
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax3)
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=.05)
cax2.remove()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess "simply adding whitespace to the left side of an axes" would translate into using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473768/4124317) from one of the posts you were linked to.