# How to set same width on shared x axis of heatmap and line plot with seaborn and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I want to create a subplot with two different heat maps and a line plot, all with shared x axis. However, when I plot the heat maps and line plot, the color bars squeeze the heat maps so the width of the heat maps are less than the line plot and the x axis are no longer aligned.

How can I fix this?

Here is an example of my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(6, 9))

sns.heatmap(np.random.random((100, 100)), ax=axarr[0], cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
sns.heatmap(np.random.random((100, 100)), ax=axarr[1], cmap=plt.cm.Greens)
axarr[2].plot([1,88], [4,99], label='Random')
axarr[2].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.35, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
```

Which results in this squeezed line plot
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you'll want to use the `cbar_ax` parameter of `sns.heatmap`.

Comment: The usual approach is to create three rows of two subplots, using `width_ratios` to make the right ones smaller. Using `cbar_ax=` to place the colorbars.

Comment: I was looking for plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True), found in this answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167360/align-matplotlib-subplot-axes-with-and-without-colorbars-for-more-than-2-axes